# Отловить ошибку обновления строки в базе данных

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Существует таблица в базе данных mysql. Одно из полей имеет флаг **unique**. Соответственно 2 или более строк с одинаковым значением поля не возможно.

Заранее в таблице уже имеется несколько записей с разными значениями этого поля. Интерфейс сайта выводит список всех строк из этой таблицы и дает возможность редактировать одну из них.

Суть проблемы состоит в том, что когда отправляется запрос на редактирование одной из строки и уникальное поле при этом совпадает с одним из других строк, то CodeIgniter просто выкидывает собственную ошибку со статусом **500**. При этом нет никакой возможности узнать, какая была ошибка.

Конечно, можно было сделать проверку на уникальность, предварительно выбрав строку с данным значением поля, но мне кажется, что это не мой путь. Как можно решить данную задачу?

Код обновления строки:

```
$sql = "UPDATE `category_portfolio` SET `name` =  ?, `description` = ?, `link` = ? WHERE `id` = ?";
$data = array($name,$desc,$link,$id);
$this->db->query($sql, $data);
```

*поле **link** уникальное*

Comment: Надеваю свой плащ волшебника: ваша ошибка не низвестна, ваша ошибка называется "повторное внесение значения в уникальное поле" и лечится (кто бы мог подумать) невнесением этого значения за счет предварительной проверки на наличие этого значения в таблице. Т.е. за счет предварительной выборки строки с этим значением.

Comment: Я вообще-то написал, что этот метод не очень, и еще писал, что ошибка вылезает **500**.

Comment: нарыл в сети, такую штуку
    
    $sql = "UPDATE IGNORE `category_portfolio` SET `name` =  ?, `description` = ?, `link` = ? WHERE `id` = ?";
    $data = array($name,$desc,$link,$id);
    $this->db->query($sql, $data);

при этом ошибки не возникает, и можно воспользоваться методом `$this->db->affected_rows();` что бы понять сколько строк было задето запросом.

какие у кого мысли по этому поводу?

Comment: Какие мысли, ну, "IGNORE" просто гасит вероятную ошибку при запросе. Все. :)
В итоге, при совпадении уникального поля ничего не будет делаться.

Comment: А что если перед вставкой/обновлением просто делать отдельный запрос на выборку? просто я изначально отказался от этой идеи потому что:  
1. Один лишний запрос.
2. Если много пользователей работают с данным интерфейсом сайта, то мне кажется, что могут возникать ошибки. Или не могут? Просто я слышал, где-то, что возможен такой исход событий. Два пользователя одновременно изменили две разные строки на одно и тоже значение. Сначала у них пройдет валидация, сперва у первого, потом у второго, а следом у одного обновление пройдет успешно, а у другого пройдет все с ошибкой, т.к. запись уже такая ест

Comment: Вообще хотелось бы почитать по этому поводу какую-нибудь книгу, что посоветуете? Ну чтобы понять, что там внутри происходит, а то так сложно принимать решения, когда не знаешь, как это работает :)

Comment: @Аркадий Кожедуб

> я ващет написал, что этот метод не очень. и еще писал, что ошибка вылезает 500.

Вы замечательно противоречите себе в двух соседних предложениях.

Answer (score 1):

В файле `config/database.php` попробуйте установить:

```
$db[...]['db_debug'] = FALSE;
```

Или обернуть запрос в блок `try-catch`.

Comment: Да, действительно, можно просто отключить вывод ошибок и самому смотреть `$this->db->_error_number()` и создавать собственное поведение при ошибке.

Answer (score 0):

В CodeIgniter наверняка есть описание кодов ошибок. И почему же валидация данных дополнительным запросом стала

> это не мой путь

Comment: Да есть, но данный запрос просто выводит ошибку с кодом 500. Как я по этому коду должен буду определить, какая была ошибка? Никак. Возможно, есть способ как-то отключить немедленное прерывание работы, когда и вывести $this->db->_error_message. Но пока что не понял, как это сделать.

Comment: Видимо, в выборке нет ничего плохого, просто я думал, что могла произойти ошибка, странно откуда я это взял. :) Всем спасибо. :)